# How to change a hook created in a plugin and assigned to a Class method in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to change the hook associated with a plugin method.
The plugin is calling the method with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', array( $this, 'vat_number_field' ) );
```

My goal is to remove that action and assign it to another hook, i've tried with the following with no success:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array( $WC_EU_VAT_Number, 'vat_number_field'), 10 );
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an action created from a class you should call that class to remove it

```
global $the_class;
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', array($the_class, 'vat_number_field') );
```

and the priority must be the same (10 by default) set to create the action.

then you can add a new method to that hook.